# Cell in Excell as variable

Tags: excel

I would like to ask for a help. I want to have cell as variable. 
For explanation:

I have this table (in sheet Test) where Column means column in second sheet with name Data

```
Name:           Column:

Manufacturer    B
Model           C
Year from       I
Year to         J
```

B is in position Data!$B$2, C is in position Data!$B$3 etc.

I would like to have function which will take this value and add number of row to this sheet. 
I mean something like this:

```
=Data! + B + 2
=Data! + B + 3
etc.
```

The right column letter would take from the sheet Test (Data!$B$2) and the number of row will take from function ROW()

I tryed something like this but:

```
=("Data!"&(Test!$B$2&""&ROW()))
```

but it gives me just text string - Data!B2 - as a result, but don´t show the content of the cell in sheet Data.

How can I do that? Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Try `=INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!" & B2 & ROW(),TRUE)` - where A2 is the name, and B2 is the column.

Comment: That´s it. Thank you so much!!